# How do I prevent oak trees from sprouting on lawn?

Tags: trees, sprouting

How do I control sprouting throughout the lawn about four feet all around?

Comment: they mow into the lawn very well, just think of them like grass clippings.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are mowing regularly you could just cut them with your lawn mower. Otherwise you could manage them with an herbicide / pesticide that would not damage the grass but would kill the unwanted oak trees.